# Model.all not working while assigning value to the name of model variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have the bit of confusion, My scenario is:

I have **model** let say `Student`, When I try to get all records its working fine like this `Student.all`.

After that, I have assigned a constant value:

```
2.3.1 :013 > Student = 1 
 => 1
```

After that whenever I try to get all students records by this command:
 `Student.all` it will give me error:

```
Student.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for 1:Fixnum
    from (irb):16
```

My question is :

- How can I get all records of a student without closing the console? by using `Student.all`.

I have tried `local_variables.each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") }` to clear all local variables.

also this one

```
(local_variables + instance_variables).each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") }
```

and

```
binding.clear
```

I am using:

- Rails 5.1.1
- ruby 2.3.1
- rvm 1.27.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try reloading the console with `reload!`?

Comment: Actually, `reload!` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, [*reload!*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21) should work. This will clear all the initiated/defined variables or constants and *reloads the Rails console with the specified environment*.

> reload!(print = true)
>
> reloads the environment

```
# File railties/lib/rails/console/app.rb, line 30
def reload!(print = true)
  puts "Reloading..." if print
  Rails.application.reloader.reload!
  true
end
```

Comment: when I do like this `Student = 1` then Student becomes local variable?

Comment: @MayurShah You are making an assignment and making Rails treat it as a variable instead of ActiveRecord model class name.

Comment: its become local variable if I am assigning like this, right?

Comment: Ofcourse yes! That is how you assign variables in Ruby.

Comment: `local_variables` give you local variables but I m not finding any value like `Student`  its always give me `=> [:_] `

Comment: I am also checking `instance_variables` but not found.

Comment: Sorry, its a `constant` actually

Comment: so how can I  find that `constant` using **console**, is there any way to get the list of `constant` or any other way.

Comment: You can use `Module.constants` which will give you all global constants defined in the Rails application including `Student`

Answer (score 1):

You should use **reload!** method.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `reload!` method at console. It will work for you.

Thanks,
Mayank Jani